# How to compute Gradient of an image with kernel in python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Using python numpy or scipy I am trying to perform cross-correlation on each pixel of an image using a 3 dimensional kernel. I am more interested in looping into each pixel and applying the kernel and looping in

i am thinking in some way like below, not sure how to complete it

```
image=cv2.imread("ABC.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
kernal=(np.ones((3, 3)) / 9) 
width, height = image.shape
destinationImg=image
"""to avoid kernal getting out side of image start in 1 and ending """
for x in xrange(1, width-1):
    for y in xrange(1, height-1):
      destinationImg[x,y]=.............
```

Comment: Your kernel has only 2 dimensions, not 3 (but it has 3 rows and 3 columns). But what is it that isn't working? By the way, have you checked out [scipy.signal.correlate2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html)?

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for code or sudo code to calculate the gradient using the given kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the OpenCV `filter2d` function to filter an image with your own custom kernel. [Here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html) is a tutorial for the same and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) is the link to the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you, But I am looking to  compute the  gradient for the input image using a given kernel. I am trying to understand how to do it in core I think.